# When a seudat mitzvah and minor fast both fall on Shabbat

Tags: shabbat, fast-days, meal-seudah, three-weeks, pidyon-haben

The 31st day of a bechor's life falls on 17 Tammuz, which this year falls on Shabbat. The ta'anit for 17 Tammuz is observed the following day, on 18 Tammuz.

Should the Pidyon HaBen be postponed to the same day, and the Seudat Pidyon HaBen interrupts the fast, or is the Seudah postponed until 19 Tammuz?

Comment: What's wrong with Saturday night?

Comment: In line with your [comment](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/93445/when-a-seudat-mitzvah-and-minor-fast-both-fall-on-shabbat/93448#comment305366_93448) indicating that this is a personal and relevant question, I’m voting to close this as psak-seeking. This is a question for your Rabbi, not random strangers on the Internet.

Comment: @DonielF this is personally relevant but I hope I've worded the question in as general terms as possible for the benefit of the community. I have consulted my rabbi and the situation is actually a bit different but I thought the question that had arisen in earlier planning was interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This site](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:L4jCVh-dyTIJ:https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/929724/jewish/When-Should-the-Pidyon-Haben-Take-Place.htm%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) explains the procedure:

> If day 31 is on Shabbat or a major Jewish holiday (other than
> Chanukah, Purim or Chol Hamoed), the pidyon haben takes place on the
> next weekday.
>
> If day 31 is a public fast day, the pidyon haben is
> held right before nightfall, and the festive meal is celebrated that
> evening. (The wine that the kohen usually drinks during the ceremony
> is drunk by a minor who is not yet obligated to fast.)

In summary, you should make the Pidyon itself, Sunday afternoon, probably after *Mincha* (i.e., between mincha & Ma'ariv). Daven Ma'ariv and then have the *seudah*.

You could also do the pidyon and seudah at night after Shabbat is done. On the same page it states:

> Although the obligation to perform the ceremony technically begins at
> nightfall following day 30 (since the Jewish day begins at nightfall),
> the custom of Ashkenazic Jews is to hold the pidyon haben in the
> afternoon of the 31st day

Note that if you are Ashkenazy (I made that assumption, hoping I'm correct) doing it in the afternoon is merely a custom, but, there's nothing halachically wrong with doing the pidyon at night.

Comment: If you're at a mincha/maariv minyan, presumably you could daven maariv after shkia, and then do the pidyon haben since it's not yet nightfall and then eat the seudah as soon as nightfall hits.

Comment: Note also that the _reason_ for the custom of doing it in the afternoon is a halachic preference which does not apply in this case. (It's to make sure that according to all opinions the correct amount of time since the birth will have passed, and that will already be true by מוצאי שבת in this case in which the פדיון הבן is delayed.)

Comment: @Rish Interesting. I think you should move this into the answer. This may imply that the pidyon and seudah really should be at night after Shabbat ends.